# How to create Excel comments that by default have no author?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

When adding an Excel comment, it is not difficult to remove the "Author:" prefix. But I find myself doing it every single time. Is there a way to remove it by default?

Answer (score 3):

There is no option to disable this in Excel.
You can however create a macro that adds an empty comment to the currently selected cell.

```
Sub AddComment()
   Dim MyComment As Comment
   Set MyComment = ActiveCell.Comment
   If MyComment Is Nothing Then
     Set MyComment = ActiveCell.AddComment
     MyComment.Text Text:=""
   End If
 End Sub
```

You could then add this macro to the ribbon or context menu.
But it requires you to select edit comment after you added it in with the macro.
It's not perfect but probably a bit less tiresome than removing the author manually from each comment.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to File -> Options
2. Under General -> Personalize your copy of Microsof Office
3. For "User name:", type a single space (`" "`)
4. Make sure "Always use these values regardless of sign in to Office." is checked

[image]

[image]

Comment: This adds " :" in every comment, which is even worse!